# Can you multiply both sides of the equation $\frac{(\text{some expression})}{x}= 0$ by $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If I have 
$$\dfrac{(\text{some expression})}{x}=0 \tag{1}$$ 
and I want to solve for something inside the "$(\text{some expression})$", can I multiply both sides by $x$? That would just leave me with 
$$(\text{some expression})=0 \tag{2}$$

The reason I ask is because it seems like I am "losing a value" similar to if I were dividing by $x$ on both sides (in case it were $x=0$, I would lose that value).

It seems like an incorrect move because $(1)$ and $(2)$ have different domains since the first one is a rational function and the second is a polynomial.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can multiply an equation by any number and preserve the equation. E.g. if you multiply the equation $x=0$ by $x$ you get $x^2=0$ which is still true. This works because $x$ is a number; for example we cannot multiply by $\frac{1}{0}$ because this is undefined.

Comment: In order for the left-hand side to be defined, you must have $x\neq0$, in which case you can multiply by a nonzero number and not lose (or introduce) any information.

Comment: You can but you have to watch out for certain equations like $\frac{x^2-7x}{x}=0$. If you multiply both sides by $x$ and solve as normal then you get $x=0,7$, but if $x=0$ then division by $0$ which is undefined so $x$ is equal to only $7$ in this case.

Comment: What happens if you were to multiply both sides to some polynomial by zero? 0=0 what kind of error is this?

Comment: But the domains still are no longer equal when I multiply by x on both sides

Comment: You can replace (expression)/x=0 with (expression=0 and x≠0). Then, if you solve expression=0 and get x=0 as a solution, you just discard it.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply both sides by $x$ after making some considerations.

Since $x$ is in the denominator, there is already a restriction that $x\neq0$, so you must keep this restriction after multiplying by $x$ (and because $x\neq0$, multiplying both sides by $x$ is legal).

So even if after you multiply both sides by $x$ you get $x=0$ as a solution, you must disregard this solution.

For example:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2-x}{x}&=0\\
x^2-x&=0,\;\;\;\color{red}{x\neq0}\\
x(x-1)&=0, \;\;\;\color{red}{x\neq0}\\
x-1&=0\\
x&=1
\end{align*}
$$
Normally, $x(x-1)=0$ would have $x=0$ and $x=1$ as solutions, but because of the restriction we ignore the solution $x=0$.

This solves the problem you mentioned in your question of the equations having different domains, because we restrict the domain of the second equation.